# Is it possible to write a single function of python module (even a class) into c/c++

Tags: python, c++

I have tried to wrap my c++ code with the method introduced in the python website: https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html

It seems I have two wrap my c++ code into a separate module. Is possible to write a single method of my module/class in c++ while others in python?

I also superficially checked the boost python and swig. It seems they also pack c++ code into a single module.

Thanks!

Comment: If you compile your c++ code, then you should be able to call the program as a command line call and pass params into it as needed. Are you looking for something more?

Comment: Can I pass python object in? I tried to ctype, and it seems I can only pass basic data types.

Comment: I am unaware anything that allows you to work with the other language directly in the other language. Calling one program to service as a service to the other is probably your best approach.